# Can ping ec2 server (ubuntu/apache) but don't get response from http request

Tags: apache, http, amazon-ec2

Background:

- OS: ubuntu
- Web Server: apache2

What works:

- I can ping the server's elastic IP (and receive a response)
- I can ssh into the server

What doesn't work:

- I cannot get any sort of http response from the server

Expected Behavior:

- When I go to http://ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/, it will serve my page, or at least give me a 404 that I can debug

Actual Behavior:

- When I go to http://ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/, it says "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com". It doesn't even give me a 404.

Rant:

Clearly the server is there because I can ssh in to that exact address and I can ping that exact IP and get a response. But when I go that exact address in my web browser it's as if it never makes it to the server. Or it's as if Amazon isn't letting http requests through, but in my security group I am clearly specifying that http requests from all sources are allowed through. Apache is definitely running, my document root is definitely set up properly, and my error and access logs don't give me anything.

Is there any sort of log in between Amazon and the server, or in between requests making it to the server and being received by Apache that would specify why it's returning "not found" rather than a 404. Can I make my Apache logs more verbose?

Thanks in advance! I've spent hours on this....

Comment: sounds like the apache is badly configured. check if exists in the process list, try to restart it. check the .htaccess file if any. did you set virtual hosts? where the default domain points?

Comment: There are three apache2 processes, I've restarted it many times, there is no htaccess file, there are many virtual hosts, not sure what you mean by default domain?

Comment: there is a default virtual host in Apache by default (/etc/apache2/sites-available/default), if you are not asking for a specific domain the request will go there. The guys on serverfault.com could help you probably faster

Comment: I set one up there, didn't change anything. I've also got a domain name set up through godaddy and going to that domain results in the same thing.

Comment: pinging the server is different than making an http request. the server may respond to ping which is made on ICMP layer or to ssh which is on port 22 usually, but not respond to a request on HTTP layer (application layer), for which port 80 needs to be open. It can be a lot of things that are setup bad with the servers, like iptables, firewall, apache directives, etc

Comment: Turns out apache was set to listen on port 8080 rather than port 80 for some reason... Thanks for the troubleshooting help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out apache was set to listen on port 8080 rather than port 80, so if you encounter this problem, try taking a look at what apache's listening to.